# Unable to compile mixed-mode C++/CLR library in VS2010 that compiles in VS2008 and compiles using MSBuild

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, unmanaged, managed-c++, mixed-mode

Here's an odd one that I came across this afternoon ... I have a mixed-mode library that I made a while back that builds just fine with VS2008. I am in the process of converting over to VS2010, and went to try and build this library using the VS2010 IDE. As expected, the IDE tells me that the solution needs to be converted to VS2010, I let it do it ... no errors in the conversion. I go to build the library, and there seems to be either a build order issue, or the build process is not able to recognize the unmanaged code from the managed code. (Example ... I'm seeing an error when a managed header is being brought in: `cannot convert int to System::String^` where there is a class method that takes a `System::String^` as one of its parameters, and sets a member variable to its value).

Ok, now step back and go back to the solution/project files before they were converted. Open the VS2010 command prompt and use MSBuild to try and build the solution without converting it first. Everything builds ok.

? Huh ?

There is obviously something that changed in the project files, but what? And why is it that the IDE is unable to build the project without converting the project files, but MSBuild chugs right through them without even a cough? Obviously, I'd like to be able to edit my source using the IDE -- has anyone else had a similar experience or heard of this issue before? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Q: Did you make sure all the references in your project are OK?  "References" are one of the first things that can get lost when MSVS "converts" a project ;)

Comment: @paulsm4 Yup, checked that. I actually went so far as to print up the project files to try and see if I could visually discern anything that might make it croak, but to no avail. :(
Don't get me wrong, I have no problem compiling from the command line, but I have a number of additions/changes to make to the library, and I really don't want to have to build that way.

Answer (score 0):

Have you compared the settings of your converted project with a newly created one in VS2010 and checked what the differences are?

Right-click the project, go to properties, and check things like "Platform Toolset" and make sure it's set to "v100", and that 'Common Language Runtime Support' is enabled on the same page, etc.. Compare with a new working project.

You can also right-click the project, unload it, right-click again and edit the the 'vcxproj' file and see if there's anything missing/wrong there.

If all else fails, I would just create a new project and copy all the code manually, if it's a conversion problem then this should definitely work.

These links might help:
[Migrating a C++/CLI Project to Visual Studio 2010](http://code.logos.com/blog/2010/04/migrating_a_ccli_project_to_visual_studio_2010.html)
[Moving a C++ Project from VS2008 to VS2010](http://syncor.blogspot.fi/2011/02/moving-c-project-from-vs2008-to-vs2010.html)
[Migrating a C++/CLI project from VS2008 to 2010](http://jkhk.wordpress.com/2011/02/16/migrating-a-ccli-project-from-vs2008-to-2010/)

Comment: I was leaning towards option #3 there (new project and copy code in), just to see if it was specifically the conversion process. I have not had time to revisit this the past few days, but hopefully will have time to give it a try this afternoon.